# Very long linear regression runtime in R

Tags: r, lme4

I'm currently creating linear mixed-effects models in R. I have got a large dataframe `df` (8000 rows), which I have cleaned up as far as possible (removed unneeded columns etc). The trouble is that the `lmer` command takes an extremely long time to run:

```
lmer_model <- lmer(myparameter ~ time * group + (1 | Pat_ID), data = df)
```

As I write, it has been running for at least 20min on a fast PC with 18% CPU usage by R. Can you recommend any methods to speed the process up, or different methods, in R or other languages?

**Edit**: The problem turned out to be a numeric column which was incorrectly formatted as character. `as.numeric` solved the issue.

Comment: the easiest way of parallelizing is using a library lm model that already has it implemented

Comment: This could be because one of the columns is a factor or coercible to factor with many different values. It will then take a lot of time to create the model matrix. What does `str(df)` return? A column that should be numeric is in fact factor or character?

Comment: Try running maybe 20 rows first to see what the elapsed time is.  Then try 100 rows.  Monitor system RAM usage too, in case there's a lot of swapping going on.

Comment: the issue turned out to be numeric values that were character. After changing that, the command was executed immediately. Thanks!